# A pretrained model for mathematical equations characters detection

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, pattern-recognition, python, digital-image-processing

I am working on a project to convert equations to LaTeX code. After segmenting out the characters, I got stuck on the detection part and was looking for some pre-trained model that could detect characters of the equation for later conversion to LaTeX. Is there any such pre-trained model available on the internet that could be used in Python to identify characters. If not then can somebody share some source to find a dataset to train such kind of model in Keras? I was able to find [one on GitHub](https://github.com/Otman404/Mathematical_Symbols_Recognition) but It doesn't detect symbols accurately.

Answer (score 2):

[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/) is a service that recognizes LaTeX symbols from handwritten figures. Their [training dataset](https://github.com/kirel/detexify-data) is freely available on Github.

Comment: can I use it in python?

Comment: which libraries would be required to train the model?

Comment: A dataset can be used in any language, as long as someone (most likely you) can program a way to read the data. Judging from [the example](https://github.com/kirel/detexify-data/blob/master/example.json), the data seems to be a not too complicated json format. I'm sure you'll be able to find a library to read .json in python, and reading the problem will probably be a bit of work, but that is often what has to be done. You could also search a bit more for references to this dataset, if you're lucky you may find someone else has already written the code you need.

Comment: Detection is not the prime subject in our project. That's why I don't want to spend much time on it. Isn't there any pre-built model in Keras/tensorflow available that would be PnP to use in code. Be it only for the detection of basic arithmetic characters and digits.

Comment: @Saqeeb Sure, I understand that you don't want to spend time on getting your dataset to work. However, most people don't, but have to do so anyway (e.g. [data scientists would rather not, but have to](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48531/)). The reality is that collecting data is tedious and it cannot always be provided on a silver platter even if those collecting the data try their best to do so. Of course, as I said, you may be lucky and find that someone else has done the work, but this is not guaranteed.